# Breaking down a SingleCellExtract, and adding a limit

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am creating an expense form and was wondering if there is a way to put a limit on how much money people can claim per day based on two cells, one that will have the name of the expense(i.e. meals expense) and one that will be the date. The rule is employees cannot spend over $60 a day on food. The current set up of the expense form is that each entry is a different receipt.

This is the formula I am using to add up all of the same expenses

```
Function SingleCellExtract(LookupValue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer, Char As String)
'Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRet As String
    For I = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
        If LookupRange.Cells(I, 1) = LookupValue Then
            If xRet = "" Then
                xRet = LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
            Else
                xRet = xRet & "" & LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
            End If
        End If
    Next
    SingleCellExtract = Left(xRet, Len(xRet) - 1)
End Function
```

But I do not know how to break that down by day and/or put a limit of $60 on it.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd have hidden columns that culminate in a hidden column containing an empty string or an error message. If you have column titles of "Category", "Date", and "Amt" and turn it into a table (Insert - Table) to make it easier on yourself for formulas, then

1. Add a new column with a title of CatDateSubtotal and a formula of `=SUMIFS([Amt],[Category],[@Category],[Date],[@Date])` *(In tables, [ColumnTitle] means all values, [@ColumnTitle] means the column value for the current row.)*
2. Add another new column with a title of Msg and a formula of `=IF(AND([@Category]="Food",[@CatDateSubtotal]>60),"Too much food for this day!","")`

Then, how you use/present this column is up to you.

Comment: I at first thought of a pivot table that you somehow had to refresh, but given that expense reports aren't gong to be that huge, this is a cleaner way with less moving parts, etc. This way, you can use formulas and conditional formatting to make issues immediately loud and clear .